# return one value from class

Tags: php, mysql, class

i have one php class

```
class veh extends dbClass
{
function smo($id)
    {
        $query="select moname from mod where id=".$id;
        $data=$this->query($query,1);
            return $data[0];
    }

}
```

i am calling that function like this

```
 $objCms=new veh();
<?=$objCms->smo(1);?>
```

the value i got from this is showing **array**, but i need to get value of **moname**

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't make any sense yet. You're not returning anything in `smo`, and we can't know what your DB class's `query()` method does. Please add more info.

Comment: I doubt you've posted all the relevant code.

Comment: sorry i forget to write return statement.. see the function now...

Comment: air.. lots of thing you have forgotten to serve..please see Pekka's comment

Comment: Make sure you keep a backup of your database. It looks like you're gonna need one. Oh, and without seeing dbClass I doubt you're going to get the answer you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your method don't returns anything, you should use `return $this->lastQuery;` or something like that
2. You are selecting, but ot fetching results. Try using [*MySQL Fetch Array*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or [*MySQL Fetch Row*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).

Example code:

```
class veh extends dbClass
{
function smo($id)
    {
        $query="select moname from mod where id=".$id;
        $this->query($query,1);
        return $this->fetchArray();
    }

}
```

Where:

- `$this->fetchArray` returns result of mysql_fetch_xxx of last query result.

Answer (score 1):

May be the method `query` return an array as a result, can you give a link to `veh` class or put `query` method implementation from `veh` class.

Answer (score 1):

You would use something like this, depending on how the `->query()` method returns it's results. We really need to see `->query()`'s body.

```
function smo($id)
{
    $query = "select moname from mod where id=" . $id;
    $data = $this->query($query,1);
    return $data[0]['moname'];
}
```

The return statement could be 1 of the following 3 things: `$data[0][0]`, `$data[0]['moname']` or `$data[0]->moname`. You can find out by using `var_dump` to see how you're able to access the moname column's value.